# Application of Weierstrass theorem

Tags: analysis

Let f be a continuously differentiable function on $[a.b]$. Show that there is a sequence of polynomials $\{P_n\}$ such that $P_n(x) \to f$ and $P'_n(x) \to f' (x)$ uniformly on $[a,b]$

My approach has been as follows.  Since f is continuously differentiable, we have $Q_n(x) \ to f'(x)$ on$ [a,b]$ uniformly (Weierstrass) .

I'm not sure how to find a polynomial that converges to f uniformly who's derivative is $Q(x)$. My first thought was $P(x)=\int_{a}^{x} Q(t)dt$. There is a relationship between uniform continuity and differentiation, but that requires convergence at a point. I'm having problems building a good argument for this part of the proof.

Comment: I rephrased and added to the question

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track; let $P_n(x) = f(a) +  \int_a^x Q_n(y)\,dy$. Then  since $P_n(a) = f(a)$ you have
$$f(x) - P_n(x) = (f(x) - f(a)) - (P_n(x) - P_n(a))$$
$$=\int_a^x f'(y)\,dy - \int_a^x P_n'(y)\,dy$$
$$= \int_a^x (f'(y) - Q_n(y))\,dy$$
If $|f'(y) - Q_n(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $y$ then the absolute value of this integral is at most $(b-a)\epsilon$, which gives what you want.

Comment: why did you add an underscored $n$ to $f$?

Comment: It was just a typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

**A more general result**

The [Bernstein polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) is defined on $[0,1]$ by
$$B_n(f)(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(\frac{i}{n})\binom{n}{i}x^i (1-x)^{n-i}$$
and if $f$ is a function with  continuous $k^{th}$ derivative then
$$||f^{(k)}-B_n(f)^{(k)}||_\infty\to_{n\to\infty}0$$

**Note**: we can pass from $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$ by the affine function $x\mapsto ax+b(1-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

All the antiderivatives of $Q_n$ are of the form $x\mapsto\int_a^xQ_n+C_n$ for some $C_n\in\Bbb R$. We can choose these $C_n$'s such that $P_n(b)=f(b)$ (or $P_n(a)=f(a)$).